# mongo db not starting up on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb on a remote machine. I restarted the machine the other day without closing the mongodb service first, when I try to restart it today using command `sudo service mogod start`, nothing happened. I checked the log file `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` there was no error message but a message that seems to be a succesfful restart atempt today. Further restart, stop, start commands are not logged to the log file. And there are no error message on either the log file or terminal window.

```
2018-06-11T22:47:50.191+0800 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2018-06-11T22:47:50.697+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-06-11T22:47:56.309+0800 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-06-11T22:47:57.269+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2018-06-11T22:47:57.269+0800 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
2018-06-19T11:48:33.985+0800 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2018-06-19T11:48:34.115+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6614 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu
2018-06-19T11:48:34.115+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.4
2018-06-19T11:48:34.115+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856
```

When I tried `sudo mongod` it comes up with `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found.` error. When I tried `sudo mongod --dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` the database start successfully.

What should I check or do to start the process using `sudo service mogod start` again?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create map "data/db" in at your disk.

Usually on Windows there should be path C://data/db. I am guessing that you should create same map on disk even though it is Ubuntu. You can try with that

Comment: my data is storing at /var/lib/mongodb

Comment: Doesn't matter, you need to have those files for starting your database with mongod command line.

I wrote something about starting mongodb, it may help aswell: http://www.damirljubicic.com/backend-development/installing-and-starting-mongodb/

Comment: I tried and created /data/db. Still nothing happened with sudo service mogod start

Comment: Can you try to create it at root directory?